# Reputation Tab under profile stopped working

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, reputation-history

Recently reputation tab under profile section is not working and shows an error page.

Here is the screenshot for that.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the immediate issue (the page erroring out), but digging into the underlying cause is going to take some time to try and reproduce.

The short version is that it seems that someone upvoted one of your answers that cites Documentation, and then undid the vote rapidly a few times. The end result was that your account was queued for a rep recalc, which I did and it appears to have fixed whatever the issue was.

Unfortunately, I didn't grab timestamps or anything that would actually help investigate this and recalcs are pretty destructive. :/

I'm going to mark this as fixed for now, but if this happens again, please let me know.

Comment: rep for documentation has happened to me quite few times in the recent past.